# Cómo subir un video con Laravel Livewire

Tags: laravel, video, laravel-livewire, filesystem

La documentacion me indica que si quiero subir archivos debo hacer lo siguiente

```
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;

class UploadPhoto extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $file;

    public function save()
    {
        $this->file->store('files');
    }
}
```

Mientras que en la vista debo tener lo siguiente

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="save">
    <input type="file" wire:model="file">

    <button type="submit">Save Photo</button>
</form>
```

Cuando quiero subir imagenes o algún otro archivo, este código me funciona perfectamente. Selecciono un archivo este viaja a una carpeta temporal, y luego al hacer click al boton del forumlario, la imagen se mueve a la carpeta files.

Mi problema viene cuando el archivo que he seleccionado es un video, luego de seleccionarlo no viaja este a la carpeta temporal, y por tanto luego quier ejecutar el *código $this->file->store('files')* me sale el error *Call to a member function store() on null*

¿Alguien sabe si debo hacer alguna configuración adicional cuando quiero subir un archivo?

Me encuentro trabajando en local con XAMPP, y mi php.ini esta configurado para subir hasta 1 gb

Answer (score 3):

Ya encontré la solución por si alguien tiene el mismo problema, el problema radica en que Livewire tiene una validación que solo permite subir archivos hasta 12 MB.

La solución es la siguiente:

Primero publiquen el archivo de configuración de Livewire, para lo cual ejecuten el siguiente comando:

```
php artisan livewire:publish --config
```

Luego de eso abran el archivo de configuración en *config/livewire.php*
y por ultimo reemplacen lo siguiente

```
return [
    ...
    'temporary_file_upload' => [
        ...
        'rules' => ['required', 'file', 'max:102400'], // (100MB max)
        ...
    ],
];
```

Espero que a alguien le sirva

Comment: porfa colócala como resuelta